# how to implement Action in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView Delegate method.?

Tags: web-services, uitableview, action

Hi friends i want know sectionIndexTitlesForTableView Action is works
i have the following code... but i want to call the web services with A/B/C/D.... Z as parameter.. So i need to know how it is?
My actual need is the products list in with starting letter As A in default , when click on B then i want to show the Product list with Starting letter as B. And also i want A.to..Z in the Right side for table view for select the letter... so i tried this but i dont know how to give the Action so please help me..

```
selectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",nil];
```

Method is:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return selectedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Question as shown below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
if (title) {
    [self webCall:title];
    [tableData setArray:nil];
    [table reloadData];
}
    return 1;
}
```